# Problems copying freetype bitmap to opengl texture

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I'm trying to generate all the bitmaps for characters from `' '` to `'~'` and add them to one long texture. I intend to position them in a fixed width texture but for now I just wanted to make sure the concept would work.

But I am having problems. Instead of getting the expected texture I just get the below for a 16px font:
[image]

It looks to me as if I'm copying it wrong but no matter what I seem to do I seem to always get the same output.

Finally, the code:

Font.h

```
#ifndef _FONT_H_
#define _FONT_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

#include "vector2.h"
#include "math_helper.h"

class Font {
public:
  Font(const std::string font_path, int size);
  ~Font();

  int get_texture() const { return texture_; }

private:
  unsigned int width_, height_, texture_;

  static FT_Library LIBRARY;
  static const char START_CHAR = ' ';
  static const char END_CHAR   = '~';

  static void initialize_library();
};

#endif
```

Font.cpp

```
#include "font.h"

FT_Library Font::LIBRARY = NULL;        

Font::Font(const std::string font_path, int size)
  : width_(64), height_(2), texture_(0) {
  initialize_library();

  FT_Face face = NULL;
  int error = FT_New_Face(Font::LIBRARY, font_path.c_str(), 0, &face);

  if(error == FT_Err_Unknown_File_Format) {
    std::cout << "Error: Unknown file format for font \"" << font_path << "\"" << std::endl;
  } else if(error) {
    std::cout << "Error: Could not open font \"" << font_path << "\"" << std::endl;
  }

  error = FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, size);
  if(error) {
    std::cout << "Error: Could not set pixel size for font \"" << font_path << "\"" << std::endl;
  }

  int num_chars = (END_CHAR - START_CHAR);
  width_ = to_nearest_pow2(num_chars * size);
  height_ = to_nearest_pow2(size);
  std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(width_ * height_, 0);
  Vector2 pen;

  for(char c = START_CHAR; c <= END_CHAR; ++c) {
    error = FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER);

    if(error) {
      std::cout << "Error: Could not load char \"" << c << "\"" << std::endl;
      continue;
    }

    FT_Bitmap bmp = face->glyph->bitmap;
    int advance = (face->glyph->advance.x >> 6);
    int bitmapWidth = bmp.width; //I have tried pitch, same problem
    int bitmapHeight = bmp.rows;

    for(int h = 0; h < bitmapHeight; ++h) {
      for(int w = 0; w < bitmapWidth; ++w) {
        int index = h * bitmapWidth + pen.x;

        buffer[index + w] = bmp.buffer[w + bitmapWidth * h];
      }
    }

    pen.x += advance;
  }

  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  glGenTextures(1, &texture_);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, width_, height_, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &buffer[0]);

  FT_Done_Face(face);
}

Font::~Font() {
  if(texture_ != 0) {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_);
  }
}

void Font::initialize_library() {
  if(Font::LIBRARY == NULL) {
    if(FT_Init_FreeType(&Font::LIBRARY) != 0) {
      std::cout << "Error: Unable to initialize FreeType Library" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Vector2 is just a simple struct with an x and y field that are initialized to 0 on construction.

`to_nearest_pow2` is defined as:

```
template<typename T>
T to_nearest_pow2(const T num) {
  T nearest = 2;

  while((nearest <<= 1) < num);

  return nearest;
}
```

Oh and here's how I am drawing it to screen (I am using orthographic projection)

```
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, test->get_texture());
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(400, 0);
  glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(400, 400);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, 400);
  glEnd();
```

**Edit**

I changed `index` to what was suggested by @shouston and now I get this output

[image]

Comment: `height_(2)` : so each glyph ends up only 2 pixels tall? Is that right?

Comment: No, the initializer list is more left over from when I set out to build it and ran into problems so got to this reduced case. The height is reassigned lower down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rescale your output image to something like 1000x60, and you'll get a surprise. Here's what paint.net made of the PNG you attached.

[image]

Obvious things first. The characters are basically there, but for some reason you;'re just rendering them very small (what value of `size` did you pass?)

Also, you're not trying to handle any of the freetype character metrics, so don't expect them to all line up nicely. yet...

Comment: For the testing I was passing a size of 12, it that not reasonable? Unless I'm getting 12px mixed up with 12pt font? and I wasn't expecting them to line up nicely, I just wanted to get the initial copying working before I bother about positioning them :)

Comment: Huzzah, you made me realize through the resizing that it looked the way it did due to the GL_CLAMP stretching it to be 400px tall which in turn heavily distorted it. I put it on a quad the size of the texture and I get exactly what I was expecting! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the index into your texture buffer:

```
int index = h * bitmapWidth + pen.x;
```

should be

```
int index = h * width_ + pen.x;
```

i.e multiply h by the full width of the texture, not the width of the glyph.

Comment: Yes - There's an assumption throughout that `width_ == bitmapWidth` .Buffer is allocated based on `width_`, but then indexed using `bitmapWidth`. the freetype docs imply that the size of bitmap you get back may not be the *exact* size that you asked for.

Comment: I have changed the code with your suggested index but just get a taller version of what I had before, see my edit :)

Comment: Can you check the value of advance? Maybe instead of pen.x += advance try pen.x += size

Comment: I get expected values for `advance` varying from 5 to 11 (from what I can see)