# freetype 2 usage in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype2

I've got a question about using freetype fonts in opengl. 
I am currently reading this tutorial http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html
and there is code example 
http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/example1.c

In method `draw_bitmap`

```
FT_Int  i, j, p, q;
FT_Int  x_max = x + bitmap->width;
FT_Int  y_max = y + bitmap->rows;


for ( i = x, p = 0; i < x_max; i++, p++ )
{
  for ( j = y, q = 0; j < y_max; j++, q++ )
  {
    if ( i < 0      || j < 0       ||
         i >= WIDTH || j >= HEIGHT )
      continue;

    image[j][i] |= bitmap->buffer[q * bitmap->width + p];
  }
}
```

they fill array `unsigned char image[HEIGHT][WIDTH];` with data
and then show image in console using `putchar`.

```
int  i, j;


for ( i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++ )
{
  for ( j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++ )
    putchar( image[i][j] == 0 ? ' '
                              : image[i][j] < 128 ? '+'
                                                  : '*' );
  putchar( '\n' );
}
```

So the question is - **this array `image` is matrix, which contains the coordinates of pixels on the screen? And in order to draw pixel I need to use glRasterPos2i?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try loading `image` as a texture, then render that texture on a quad.

This guy had issues, and solved them, should be the code you're looking for:

[Problems copying freetype bitmap to opengl texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209494/problems-copying-freetype-bitmap-to-opengl-texture)